# Another's vs Other's

Tags: american-english, british-english

Good afternoon! I found a lot of examples of using the phrase **other's** on the Internet. As I know, **other** itself can't be a pronoun. Shouldn't I use **another's** OR **the other's** instead?

Here are some examples:

1. You take on **other's** problems as your own.
2. Call attention to **other's** mistakes indirectly.
3. Many of us get jealous and angry at **other's** potential successes.

Comment: That's really hard to answer without any of those examples. Could you edit your question and include a few?

Comment: Others is **plural**, so use the rule about possessives of plural nouns which end in 's' - an apostrophe after the 's' - **you take on others' problems as your own**. **Another** (an other) is **singular** so - **call attention to another's mistakes indirectly.** Summary: others' _things_ for more than one, another's _thing or things_ for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that's better.
In all three of your examples, there is a mistake, but it's not a case of other versus another, but combination of plural and possessive.

Let's take

> You take on other's problems as your own.

It's a general statement about taking on problems of *other people* (many of them), in other words, problems of *others*.

When making a possessive out of a plural ending in -s, the apostrophe goes after the pluralising *s*: **others' problems**.

The correct spelling would be

> You take on **others'** problems as your own.

Same for the other two.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!